# sorting a list of strings according to an array of integers

Tags: java

I have an array list `[Mod8, Mod5, Mod9, Mod10]` and an integer array `[1, 0, 2, 3]`. I need an output list `[Mod5, Mod8, Mod9, Mod10]` according to the numbers in the integer array. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: can you use other data structures?

Comment: At first I was thinking associative array, but didn't think Java did those natively. Closest is a HashMap, but the cleanest solution "academically" is probably just to build a simple class with the ModN value and the integer, and then implement Comparable interface to compare the integer values of each instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> original = new ArrayList<String>();
original.add("Mod8");
original.add("Mod5");
original.add("Mod9");
original.add("Mod10");

int[] sortIndexArray = new int[] { 1, 0, 2, 3 };

List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(original.size());
for (int i = 0; i < sortIndexArray.length; i++) {
  sorted.add(original.get(sortIndexArray[i]));
}

System.out.println(sorted); // [Mod5, Mod8, Mod9, Mod10]
```

Comment: c'mon, you should know better than to just post a random code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Since your 2 lists seem strongly tied together, I would create a `Pair<Int,String>` object to tie them together, and write a comparator for that `Pair` object.

Otherwise you have to keep the two in sync as they change, and that's going to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a class which implements the comparable interface. Then override the compareTo() function using the integer values to compare them in a way you need.
Hope that helps!